# Spring data jpa - While Updating a parent, how to delete the childs associated with it (based on id) from database and add the new child

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have Parent entity Head and associated childs are Detail and Comment mapped using onetomany. I have only one DAO which is HeadDao. ProjectNumber PK in Head and FK in Detail and Comment. I'm trying to figure out how to delete the Child Comment using the projectNumber without writing the DAO for the child.

Scenario is, while updating the Head i want to first delete the existing (associated) Comments from the database (using the projectNumber) and then add the new comments which are coming in the request. Could any one help me with this.
Below are Entity classes (FYI Comment class has composite id, but i not pasted it here)

```
@Entity(name = "Head")
@Table(name = "HEAD")
public class Head {
@Id
@Column(name = "PRJ_NBR")
private Integer projNumber;
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "head",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = 
true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Detail> detailsList = new ArrayList<Detail>();

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "head",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = 
true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Comment> commentsList = new ArrayList<Comment>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PRJ_CMT")
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class Comment {
@Transient
private Integer projectNumber;

@JsonIgnore
@EmbeddedId
private CommentCompositeId id;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PRJ_NBR", updatable=false, insertable=false)
private Head head;
}

@Transactional
@Repository
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
public abstract interface HeadDao  extends JpaRepository<Head, 
Serializable>
{
 public abstract List<Head> findByProjNumber(Integer paramInteger);

 public abstract List<Head> findAll();

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public abstract Head saveAndFlush(Head paramHead);

  public abstract List<Head> findByCusSysId(Integer paramInteger);

  public abstract Integer deleteByProjNumber(Integer projNumber);
 }

 While adding i'm using below code
this.headDao.saveAndFlush(head);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST to the ManytoOne (comment) side (cascade all should be present on the onetomany - head).
Now when i'm adding the list of comments, its deleting the comments (for the project number) which are not present the current list and updating other comments

Answer (score 0):

How about simply by replacing `commentsList` for existing `head` ?

Create setter for `head.commentsList`.

Replace comments with `newComments = new ArrayList<Comment>()` that is populated with the new comments, then `head.setCommentsList(newComments)`.

Persist head, `this.headDao.saveAndFlush(head);`.

Comment: Tried that, this will simply add the new list to the database, it wont delete the existing ones.
FYI: i'm not doing fetch initially. I'm Just taking the head object which is coming as a request to the API and calling the update dao

Comment: did i understand correct: you do not fetch the correspondin head from db before updating the comment list ? but store something that comes outside as request response, with new comments ?

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly, and Thanks for your previous comment (I think you deleted it).  I tried adding cascade all on comments side, but it gave error like _object references an unsaved transient instance _. They i tried PERSIST it worked.
Solved it by adding (cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) on Comment side

Comment: removed it was not sane :) you need to fetch the head by the id you got from the request i think. then update the fetched head with the comments. i'm not sure if this helps but is the correct way still

Comment: Could you edit your answer for adding the PERSIST! so that i can accept the answer?

Comment: you mean adding saveOrUpdate() or so ?

Comment: i mean i do not know about your DAO enough.

Comment: DAO is pretty much what i have posted in the description..
I used the cascade all on head side and used the cascade persist on the Comment.
And i called the saveAndFlush method in DAO, so it updated the comments if it already existed and deleted any other comment which is not present in the list.